# Problems with StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor class in Spring Framework

Tags: spring, spring-amqp

I have a problem with class "StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor" because I don't know how to use it because there is no source example on Internet, so I ask you for a help :). So if you have any experiences with usage of this class please can you just post some simple source example here, I would be grateful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the discussion at [StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?117427-Handling-Failures-With-StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean) .

You need to have a [retryTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/retry/support/RetryTemplate.html) with a [retryPolicy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/retry/RetryPolicy.html) for this .

See the reference [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/retry/interceptor/StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.html) .

Comment: the last 3 links are dead.